# trying to display all the different username in a table if multiple only display it once

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display all the usernames in a table however if there is multiple of the same user only display once. It currently works on the first row in the database but doesn't work on the other users in the table

```
<?php 
$sql = " SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever = '".$_SESSION['name']."' LIMIT 1 ";
$mes = $pdo->query($sql);

while($mess = $mes->fetch())
{
?>         
<li><?php echo " ".$mess['sender']." <a href='my-messages.php?sender=".$mess['sender'] ."' > View</a> " ?></li>                   

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: *"it currently works on the first row in the database"* - and you're `LIMIT`ing it to "1".

Comment: If you only need `sender`, why do you `SELECT *`?

Comment: "but doesnt work on the other users in the table". Well `LIMIT 1` make sure it will not work on other users.

Comment: i need it to select all of  the sender and if there is more then one of them only display once

Comment: You're leaving yourself open to SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Select DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT SENDER FROM messages WHERE reciever = '".$_SESSION['name']."'
```